# Keeping text within UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have some text that animates (it rolls up and changes to the next number and has a background image behind it. Is it possible to only show the text and its subsequent animation within the bounds of the UIImageView. I know I could simply take a chunk of the background and overlay it on top of the UIImage and the text but it's not really ideal.

if it's at all helpful or relevant here's the code that's creating the animation

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func pushTransition(duration:CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation:CATransition = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
            kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        animation.type = kCATransitionPush
        animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
        animation.duration = duration
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: kCATransitionPush)
    }
}
```

Edit: a bit more clarification, the labels being updated are stored within an array, the code cycles through them and updates them if it needs to. The code thats updating the code is below

```
 for i in 1...updateArrayLength{
            if updateArray[i-1] == "1"{
                let newNumber = charactersAsStrings[i-1]

                let label = labelArray[i-1]
                //if let aLabel = label{
                label.isHidden = false
                    label.pushTransition(duration: 0.2)
                    label.text = "\(newNumber)"
                    //label.sizeToFit()
                //}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit more code is needed to fully answer this, but I believe setting `view.clipsToBounds = true` should solve this if I'm understanding your question correctly.